# Runtime Exception,view.InflateException,reflection.InvocationTargetException and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, exception, out-of-memory, invocationtargetexception, inflate-exception

I'm developing my first game for android.I've been running and testing my codes then and there in my android phone(Samsung Galaxy S2).In the finishing stages of my game,i added google admob services.Once it was added my game began to slow down.Game shuts down at some point with list of exceptions in the logcat.None of these logcat entries provide me a clue of what and where my error is from.

This is my logcat entry,

```
03-19 19:53:34.638: D/AndroidRuntime(637): Shutting down VM
03-19 19:53:34.638: W/dalvikvm(637): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41587ba8)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637): Process: btdw.agilan.minesweeper, PID: 637
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{btdw.agilan.minesweeper/btdw.agilan.minesweeper.MenuPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #111: Error inflating class <unknown>
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:343)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at btdw.agilan.minesweeper.MenuPage.onCreate(MenuPage.java:80)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  ... 11 more
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  ... 23 more
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.<init>(BufferedInputStream.java:96)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.gesture.GestureStore.load(GestureStore.java:281)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at android.gesture.GestureStore.load(GestureStore.java:275)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.google.ads.internal.k.a(SourceFile:42)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:514)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:370)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:125)
03-19 19:53:34.648: E/AndroidRuntime(637):  ... 26 more
03-19 19:54:35.163: I/Process(637): Sending signal. PID: 637 SIG: 9
```

I couldn't even find if the error is from java code or xml file.Please help me figure out this.

NOTE:In my Toshiba at10-a(Tablet) this game runs smooth without such exceptions.

I want my game to work on all devices in the same way.Please help me finish this first game of mine.

This is my XML file menupage.xml,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/waterglass" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/menublanket"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bHighScores"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="High Scores" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNewGame"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bHighScores"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="New Game" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bExit"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bHighScores"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Exit" />




    </RelativeLayout>

      <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivAnimatedSmiley"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             />

    <btdw.agilan.minesweeper.Title
        android:id="@+id/tvMinesweeperTitleOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Minesweeper"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <btdw.agilan.minesweeper.Title
        android:id="@+id/tvMinesweeperTitleIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Minesweeper"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/ibSettingsImage"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/settings"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/relativeLayout1"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        />

   <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/ivLikeUs"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/fb"
         android:layout_alignRight="@id/relativeLayout1"
         android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1" 
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

        />


       <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/googleAd" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adUnitId="a15318aa0c2dc06"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
         ads:unLoadOnPause="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
        />
        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Are you inflating heavy images or lot of them, OutOfMemoryError? in the UI thread?

Comment: Show us that XML file

Answer (score 2):

Check this Android developer link. And have the images in appropriate folder with appropriate sizes. When you don't have images in appropriate size, the os will try to adjust the image size itself and that causes out of memory exception.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I've done it already.I placed images with different dpi's in different drawable folders.